# Creating buttons with Python GUI

Tags: python, class, user-interface, button, tkinter

I am trying to create Buttons in Python with classes, but when running it the buttons do not appear. Following is my code

```
#Button_2
#Using Classes

from Tkinter import * 

class Application(Frame):
    """A GUI application with three button"""

    def _init_(self, master):
        """ Initialise the Frame. """
        Frame._init_(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        #"""Create three buttons"""
        #Create first buttom
        self.btn1 = Button(self, text = "I do nothing")
        self.btn1.grid()

        #Create second button
        self.btn2 = Button(self)
        self.btn2.grid()
        self.btn2.configure(text = "T do nothing as well")

        #Create third button
        self.btn3 = Button(self)
        self.btn3.grid()    
        self.btn3.configure(text = "I do nothing as well as well")

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Lazy Button 2")
    root.geometry("500x500")
    app = Application(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: to add to mgilson's answer, your indentation is non existent.

Comment: I indented your code for you so that it renders properly on SO.  Part of the problem with the rendering is that it appears you had tabs and spaces.  (I converted them all to 4-spaces per level as specified in PEP8).  Hopefully that was just to post the code on SO, but if not, **Please do not mix tabs and spaces in your code** and preferably use 4-spaces per indentation level as I've done above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first problem is that you have declared your following code:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Button 2")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()code here
```

inside the class itself. It should be outside, so this an indentation problem (maybe stackoverflow problem with indents?).

secondly I simplified the code to get it to run

```
from Tkinter import * 

class Application(Frame):
      """A GUI application with three button"""

     #create a class variable from the root (master):called by the constructor
     def _init_(self, master):
          self.master = master

     #simple button construction
     # create a button with chosen arguments
     # pack it after the creation not in the middle or before

     def create_widgets(self):
          #"""Create three buttons"""
          #Create first button
          btn1 = Button(self.master, text = "I do nothing")
          btn1.pack()

          #Create second button
          btn2 = Button(self.master, text = "T do nothing as well")
          btn2.pack()

         #Create third button
         btn3=Button(self.master, text = "I do nothing as well as well")
         btn3.pack()

  #must be outside class definition but probably due to stackoverlow
  root = Tk()
  root.title("Lazy Button 2")
  root.geometry("500x500")
  app = Application(root)
  #call the method
  app.create_widgets()
  root.mainloop()
```

This is a starting point and definitely works as proven below:

[image]

You can probablty muck around with the grid() instead of pack and call the method from the def **init** constructor. Hope it helps.

This calling method also works:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Button 2")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root).create_widgets()  #creates and invokes
root.mainloop()
```

My final try also works:

```
def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.create_widgets()
```

followed by:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Button 2")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

The final code:

```
from Tkinter import * 

class Application(Frame):
"""A GUI application with three button"""

def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.create_widgets()



def create_widgets(self):
    #"""Create three buttons"""
    #Create first buttom
    btn1 = Button(self.master, text = "I do nothing")
    btn1.pack()

    #Create second button
    btn2 = Button(self.master, text = "T do nothing as well")
    btn2.pack()

    #Create third button
    btn3=Button(self.master, text = "I do nothing as well as well")
    btn3.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Button 2")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You need your "constructor" method to be named `__init__`, not `_init_`.  As it is written, your `grid` and `create_widgets` methods never get called since `_init_` never gets called.