# Python 3.2, Tkinter class declarations, class undefined when subclassing

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, declaration

I'm learning python and encountering issues with what appears to be class decorators from tkinter. I can get tkinter to work as long as I never try to decorate with Frame. The code below gives me no errors, and no window. For whatever reason, the class I define, never gets defined. Below is my code. Below that is testing i've done based on similar questions regarding tkinter.

```
>>> from tkinter import *
import tkinter
class Apples:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()
        self.button = Button(frame, text="Quit", fg="blue", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.hellos = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hello)
        self.hellos.pack(side=LEFT)
    def say_hello(self):
        print("Hello World!")
root = Tk()
app = Apples(root)
root.mainloop()
```

No window shows up. No error. So I check on the class...

```
>>> test = Apples(root)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    test = Apples(root)
NameError: name 'Apples' is not defined
>>>
```

I found a similar question [Creating buttons with Python GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070065/creating-buttons-with-python-gui)  and attempted the code from pythonMan. I still am encountering the same class declaration issue.

```
>>> from tkinter import * 

class Application(Frame):
"""A GUI application with three button"""

def __init__(self,master):
    self.master = master
    self.create_widgets()



def create_widgets(self):
    #"""Create three buttons"""
    #Create first buttom
    btn1 = Button(self.master, text = "I do nothing")
    btn1.pack()

    #Create second button
    btn2 = Button(self.master, text = "T do nothing as well")
    btn2.pack()

    #Create third button
    btn3=Button(self.master, text = "I do nothing as well as well")
    btn3.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("Lazy Button 2")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
>>> Application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#58>", line 1, in <module>
    Application
NameError: name 'Application' is not defined
>>>
```

I can think something is not being declared properly, but is not generating a syntax error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your first code snippet runs fine for me.  I get an application window with two buttons.

Comment: I...am at a loss. I type the first code in, line for line, into IDLE. It worked just fine this time. It had to have been an indentation problem, but I can't find it.

Comment: I can't answer this answered question for another 7 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need an ">>>" sign.

"from Tkinter import *"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is properly reproduced in the second part of your question, you're defining your class incorrectly. You have `def __init__` at the same level of indentation as `class Application(Frame)`. Your methods need to be indented for them to be part of the class.

The code in the first part of your question works fine for me.